# Overlapping axis label

Tags: gnuplot

I am working with a gnuplot multiplot and struggling with the yAxis tic labels. See the image below.

[image]

My problem is shown in the red circle as there are -10 from the upper and 1200 from the lower at the exact same position. But I dont like it in this way (as most people would do).

I have tried to fix it using ytics to get rid of the 1200 from the lower plot but that didnt work.
Margins have not worked for me either.

Anyone an idea (or solution) how to fix it (because it is quite annoying)

Comment: What do you mean by "setting ytics and margins didn't work"? How have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Setting tics as like in the answer by sweber, cuts out some of the values. Margins (especially top and/or bottom) gave undesired spacing between both plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify

```
set ytics <start>, <step>, <stop>
```

to control the range for which the tics are created.
So, for the lower plot

```
set ytics -600, 300, 900
```

May be fine to remove the 1200 tic.

Another way is to adjust the yranges so that the 1200 and -10 just do not overlap.